# How to show picture from predictions? (CNN AI predictions)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, conv-neural-network, prediction

I am trying to get the images from a list of predictions called 'classes'

```
classes = model.predict(test_set)
```

and to match the result with the picture, I am finding a little troubling to do.
Below is what I have done to try and show the images with the result.

```
location = 2  #Iterate through list of predictions.
print(categories[np.argmax(classes[location])]) #Shows result from prediction
plt.figure()    
plt.imshow(test_set[location])  # Shows image
```

The error I get doing this is:
"could not broadcast input array from shape (32,224,224,3) into shape (32,)"
if I do

```
plt.imshow(classes[location])  # Shows image
```

then I get: TypeError: Invalid shape (2,) for image data

Answer (score 1):

Your image data may need to be processed to the appropriate format (see [article](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/#visualize-the-data)).  Try this:

```py
plt.imshow(test_set[location].numpy().astype("uint8"))
```

Also, your `classes[location]` is not an image, so you probably should not be trying to pass it to `plt.imshow`.  Instead, it is the prediction result.  I suspect it is the softmax probability vector with two elements (?for binary classification you may be attempting).

Comment: Thank you. I'm quite new to it and using google.colab. I am finding it hard to know what each object type is (unlike vs). I implemented your code and it returned: "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'numpy'"

Comment: About the softmax probability vector. I believe so. It returns an accuracy and a loss when i check the classes.

Comment: @randomUser1212421, if you are using a public dataset, then it would be helpful if you share the name and location/URL of the dataset to better help you  Otherwise, start by using `type()` to determine the data type of `test_set` and `test_set[location]`.

Comment: Good Idea, I am using a dataset from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/constantinwerner/human-detection-dataset
I put it into 3 folders, test, validation, train.

Comment: I implemented the 'type()' (thankyou for providing that) and it showed that the 'test_set' is a keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator and classes is a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @randomUser1212421, good job on getting data types and thanks for providing the dataset source.  Your dataset is in the form of an iterator, which means that you must apply the `.take()` method to first extract a batch of images.  The batch size will be that of the default, unless you specified a batch size when you read in the data.  If you follow the article link I provided in my answer, you will see how to do this.

Comment: I just got back on this. How would I use the ".take()"? Can I use it on the list of predictions? for example: classes = model.predict(test_set).take()